# android studio unable to connect to adb.Check the Event log for possible issues verify that your localhost entry is pointing to 127.0.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

android studio unable to connect to adb.Check the Event log for possible issues verify that your localhost entry is pointing to 127.0.0.1...

[image]